# How do I access data from a top-level document in a Cloud firestore trigger with Cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Example: If my trigger is `onWrite` on a path such as `Users/{userId}/Billings/{billingId}`, how can I access user document data:

```
functions
.firestore
.document('Users/{userId}/Billings/{billingId}')
.onWrite((change, context) => {

});
```

I know that I can access billing data via change and wild cards userId and billingId via `context.params`.

How would I access user document data that triggered this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly get the user document from the parameters. But you can determine the path from the parameters, and then load the document with the Admin SDK.

```
admin.firestore().doc(`users/${context.params.userId}`).get()...
```